# Combine two iterables within any built-in function

Tags: python, iterator

So this is a normal any() method checking if the iterable returns True in any of its elements:

```
list_a = ['test', 'hello']
list_b = ['test', 'bye']
name = 'test'
any(name == item for item in list_a)
True
```

But what about combining two iterables?

This works:

```
name = 'hello'
any(name == item_a for item_a in list_a or name == item_b for item_b in list_b)
True
```

This doesnt:

```
name = 'bye'
 any(name == item_a for item_a in list_a or name == item_b for item_b in list_b)
False
```

This can be simplyfied to:

```
any([True] or [False]) vs any([False] or [True])
```

How can it be transformed to:

```
any([True, False]) or any([False, True])
```

Any way to combine those two iterators within the any() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting for a moment `list_a` to something with a `False` truth value helps reveal what's wrong with your first approach:

```
list_a = []
any(name == item_a for item_a in list_a or name == item_b for item_b in list_b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'item_b' is not defined
```

This should help convince you that the `any` line is interpreted like

```
any(name == item_a for item_a in (list_a or name == item_b) for item_b in list_b)
```

Because `or` short-circuits and `list_a` is `True` in your original example the `or name == item_b` has no effect there.

Your desired behavior can be achieved by `or`ing two `any` statements or `itertools.chain`ing the operands of `any`

```
import itertools as it
name = 'bye'
any(it.chain((name==item_a for item_a in list_a), (name==item_b for item_b in list_b)))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want, but this is simpler:

```
any(name == item for item in list_a + list_b)
```

#### take 2:

getting attribute value from objects:

```
any([any(name==item.get_value() for item in list1), any(name==item.obtain_value() for item in list2)])
```

It lost its simplification factor, so it doesn't really address your question.
It retains its lazy evaluation short circuiting though.

Comment: It could be two iterables with different fields names like any(name == item_a.field for item_a in list_a or name == item_b.name for item_b in list_b)

Comment: Ah, in that case, it is indeed oversimplified.

Comment: Pretty sure your take 2 doesn't work because `any` takes exactly one argument, so your outer `any` will raise. And if it worked your inner `any`s would kill the outer `any`s short-circuiting because all function arguments are evaluated before the function is called.

Comment: Good catch, I included the two arguments in a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

`any` accepts a single iterable. For simple lists, you could just do

```
any(['hello'=word for word in list1 + list2])
```

For other type of iterators, you can use `itertools.chain` to produce a single iterable from them.

In your case however, the simplest thing seems

```
if 'hello' in list1 + list2
```

Comment: Maybe I oversimplified the answer using list of strings, it could be two iterables returning objects like any(name == item_a.field for item_a in list_a or name == item_b.name for item_b in list_b)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get `mylist.field` directly. You should either use something `map(getattr, ...)` or, better, a list comprehension. Either way, `any` accepts a single iterable, so you have to combine the two, either by `list1+list2`, or with `itertools.chain`